# How to store images on a separate server with Drupal 7

Tags: media

How to store (upload and move) images to a separate server (possibly with a mounted drive) with Drupal 7 and still be able to select images from the Media browser?

Also, how to serve the images from that separate server instead of the one that Drupal resides?